# Add Firebase to UWP (Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: firebase, uwp

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with Firebase + UWP (Universal Windows Platform) integration? My client is using the UWP app and they have a 360 GA account that they want to link with. They need to set up a Firebase project but don't think UWP is supported atm.

I'm not a developer and couldn't find any [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides) for adding Firebase to UWP app, is there another solution?